# Android - Custom adapter, GetView position is not incrementing correctly

Tags: android, listview, adapter

My custom adapter contains a getView method and the getView's position is not incrementing correctly.The side effects is that all values is presented in both layouts (row_chat_me & row_chat_others). 
The IsMsgFromMe identifies correctly who the author of the message is (message.GetFrom()). chatMsgList is an ArrayList containing Message objects.

Thanks!

```
public class ChatAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Message> {
public ChatAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Message> messages) {
    super(context, 0, messages);
}

public boolean IsMsgFromMe(Message message) {
    boolean isSenderMe = ChatFragment.username.equals(message.GetFrom());
    return isSenderMe;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder = null;

    // Get the data item for this position
    Message message = ChatFragment.chatMsgList.get(position);

    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        //Check who has sent the message me or someone else...
        if (IsMsgFromMe(message)) {

            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_chat_me, parent, false);

            holder.chatFrom = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_message_me_from);
            holder.chatMessage = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_message_me_message);
            holder.chatTime = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_message_me_time);

        } else {

            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_chat_others, parent, false);

            holder.chatFrom = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_message_others_from);
            holder.chatMessage = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_message_others_message);
            holder.chatTime = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_message_others_time);

        }
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    // Populate the data into the template view using the data object
    holder.chatFrom.setText("From: " + message.GetFrom());
    holder.chatMessage.setText(message.GetMsg());
    holder.chatTime.setText("Date: " + message.GetTime());

    // Return the completed view to render on screen
    return convertView;
}

public static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView chatFrom;
    public TextView chatMessage;
    public TextView chatTime;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your code above, in getView(), when convertView!=null, maybe convertView was inflated from R.layout.row_chat_me instead of R.layout.row_chat_others (and .

So, you should override **getItemType()** and **getViewTypeCount()** to define 2 (or more) item view type in adapter.

More detail you can read here: http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296 (part Different list items’ layouts)

Comment: Hi i have implemented this solution but unfortunately the issue still remains the same. Here is how i have implemented it http://pastebin.com/tSqtz4aJ

Comment: @user2407226 i think you should remove notifyDataSetChanged(); in getView(...). If it still not working, please show me the Logcat or more detail about this issue (I'm not really understand what "position is not incrementing correctly" is).

Comment: I have now found a solution to my question but unfortunaly i have some issues when scrolling the list and my solution for that problem works but it is a terrifying solution and destroys the purpose off the view Holder pattern. I will post a new question on stackoverflow to avoid future confusion, "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28356606/android-view-holder-does-not-update-listview-correctly"

The solution was to remove the second listview and create a left and right side in the row.
See code "http://pastebin.com/6WSjQAbs",
"http://pastebin.com/xMFCm62s",
"http://pastebin.com/rCbeBS6E".

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is that you make use of the List of Messages passed into your adapter instead of referencing a list from the `ChatFragment`. So I would modify the adapter code like this:

```
public class ChatAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Message> {

private ArrayList<Message> messages;

public ChatAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Message> messages) {
    super(context, 0, messages);
    this.messages = messages;
}

...
```

Unless you have different backgrounds for the 2 chat rows or there's some other major difference between the 2 chat rows, I think you need just one row layout.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder = null;

    // Get the data item for this position
    Message message = messages.get(position);

    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_chat, parent, false);

        holder.chatFrom = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_message_from);
        holder.chatMessage = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_message_message);
        holder.chatTime = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_message_time);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    // Populate the data into the template view using the data object
    holder.chatFrom.setText("From: " + message.GetFrom());
    holder.chatMessage.setText(message.GetMsg());
    holder.chatTime.setText("Date: " + message.GetTime());

    // Return the completed view to render on screen
    return convertView;
}
```

Sample single row layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
       android:id="@+id/txt_message_time"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="25dp"/>

    <TextView
       android:id="@+id/txt_message_from"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="25dp"
       android:layout_below="@+id/txt_message_time" />

    <TextView
       android:id="@+id/txt_message_message"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_below="@+id/txt_message_from"
       android:layout_height="50dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: unfortunately this solution did not make it work but you have a point...
Thanks for the help...

Comment: Could you post your `row_chat_me` and `row_chat_others` layout files?

Comment: Here is the xml code http://pastebin.com/aBR64G7h.
And here is the updated code for the ChatAdapter pastebin.com/tSqtz4aJ

Comment: I have found a strange thing under debbuging, the parent parameter in convertView is sometime the opposite from the sender but  how to fix it or is it correct behavior?

Comment: @user2407226 Are you trying to implement a chat view? Why are you using 2 list views?

Comment: Yes a chat view and the "my" messages shall be shown in one side (listview_chat_message_me)  and messages from others shall be shown on the other side (listView_chat_messages_others).
Reason for using 2 different listviews is because i though that it would be the easiest solution to reach this goal.

Comment: Thanks for helping but this solution will show all messags consecutively, i wannt messages sent by me shown on left side and messages sent by others shown on right side

Comment: Do you want to implement a WhatsApp style chat view or do you want 2 different list views side by side?

Comment: I want 2 different listviews side by side.

Comment: Do the rows for the 2 list views have different backgrounds? Could you post your activity's code? I would like to see how you instantiated your list views.

Comment: The listViews have the same background color but i wannt to be able to change it in the future :)
Code for Chat http://pastebin.com/1xU71Zav.
Code for Group http://pastebin.com/7LSqwzEN

Comment: I think you over complicated your implementation. You shouldn't need to initialize your list views every time a new message is added to the list of existing messages. You can instantiate it once, when the Fragment's view is created and then reuse it whenever you need to. Since you are using just one adapter for both list views, you can set the backgrounds of the row views for the different list views in the adapter. You can also instantiate 2 different `ChatAdapter`s and populate them differently.